# scalesPageToFit for webView is not working with iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, ios9.3

I have UIWebview in storyboard, I am loading HTML pages inside the view.
till iOS 9.2 it is working great as desire, but when i am running same in iOS 9.3 the page is appeared with zoom in by default.
I have set scalesPageToFit property.

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
```

I have too tried setting frame programatically for UIWebview.

This are my Meta tag from HTML..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.2, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

i have tried with meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

As suggested in many post i have tried with.

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", (int)self.view.frame.size.width]];
```

Comment: I have the same problem with WKWebView on 9.3, as I mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633066/wkwebview-viewport-shrink-to-fit-not-working-on-ios-9-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had quite the same issue for me the solution was using this code bellow

```
    webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    float width = webview.frame.size.width;
    float scale = width/770;

    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom=%.2f;",scale];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

I am aware of that this is hacky workaround. The number 770 is the ratio between width(points) and scale which I need for fitting in a content of web page to webview.

**UPDATE**

I found out that above solution time to time cause not correctly scaling letters in specific html tags, that's why I came with javascript, which changes directly meta tag with name viewport (code bellow)

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content','width=device-width; initial-scale=%.2f; user-scalable=no;');",scale];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //make sure that the page scales when it is loaded :-)
    theWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    return YES;
}
```

seem to be the suitable solution