# Content Fit Inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

It is very Common question but I stuck badly in the problem.My problem define in the screen shot below.
[image]

I want to set the content inside the webview according to the screen width.I have a tableview Where a uiwebView on each tableView Cell.

I used many things like `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;` and autoresizemask but can't solve it.

Any Help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426007/scalespagetofit-for-webview-is-not-working-with-ios-9-3

Answer (score 0):

In your case `webView.scalesPageToFit = true` but still webview not fit it seems to problem with tableviewcell size of webview maybe initially not found accurate reloading tableview may solve this issue try below code if that related to tableview reload this will help

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.YOUR_TABLEVIEW.reloadData()
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the Fast response, The issue is raised when the webview.scrollview.contentsize.width > screen width , so i want a way to adjust the content w.r.t screen width because the scroll is disabled.

Comment: `webView.scalesPageToFit = true` will help to set the same size

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       //Access web view form cell here
       // then use [webObj sizeToFit];
       // then get height of web view and return it as height of cell

    }
```

Comment: @Manngesh I dont want to adjust the height i already didi it , i want to adjust the content horizontally

Comment: do you want scrollview to scroll content horizontally?

Comment: Got it.Your content inside web view is floating.am i right?

Comment: No see in my screen shot my content clips from the right side on small width screen , i want to make it adjustable according to the screen width

Comment: Can you show the code of how you embed the web view in cell?I mean any constraints??

Comment: uiwebview inside  Custom tableViewCell with border contrains like leading ,trailing ,top , bottom

Comment: try equal width constraint instead.may it will help